# How can I manage child rows in DataTables using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I am trying to bind a child table to a parent table with drill-down [build a DataTable where the main table data row can be expanded to show an embedded child row data]
I follow Ajax loaded row details blog [this](https://datatables.net/blog/2017-03-31)

I am not able to figure out how this can be managed when the data for the child table is coming through a separate AJAX call which then creates a dynamic table build a child DataTable where each row can be expanded to show an embedded parent DataTable

I had already managed it through an ajax call, and data coming from DB as except
every time I open drill down it adds new `<tr>` into the parent table for child row that's why the child table `<tr>`  layout  tables Exceed their Size from a parent table

I  add an image [table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2tL3.png) for reference please review the table structure

Here the table structure after drill down open how it appends the `<tr>` inside the parent table according to it's raw [table structure](https://jsfiddle.net/kkoUser/0osgqjtw/25/)

below is the code

```
// Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#my-table tbody').off('click', 'td.details-control');
    $('#my-table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        console.log(tr);
        row = exporterListTable.row( tr );
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(Details(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
```

and then the format() will be

```
    function format ( rowData ) {
        div = $('<div/>')
            .addClass( 'loading' )
            .addClass( 'table_child')
            .text( 'Loading...' );
        $.ajax( {
            url: 'get-table-items(details)',
            data: {
                yearMonth: rowData[1],
                productFilterName
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function ( json ) {
                div.html(json)
                div.removeClass( 'loading' )
                if(json.length > 0){
                    div.append("<tr><th>TABLE FIELD</tr>")
                    var len = json.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        div.append("<tr><td>"+JSON+"</td></tr>");
                    }
                }
            }
        } );
            return div;
    }
```

and here is an ajax call

```
 function ExportersDetails ( rowData ) {
        div = $('<div/>')
            .addClass( 'loading' )
            .addClass( 'table_child')
             .addClass('table-responsive')
            .text( 'Loading...' );
        $.ajax( {
            url: 'get-exporters-details',
            data: {
                exporter: rowData[1],
                overallFilter
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function ( json ) {
                div.html(json)
                div.removeClass( 'loading' )
                if(json.length > 0){
                    div.append("<tr><th>TABLE FIELD</th></tr>")
                    var len = json.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        div.append("<tr><td>"+JSON+"</td></tr>");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return div;
    }
```

please help me to add the `<table>` before the `<tr>` tag add, I already made many changes seems doesn't help!

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: Hi, that is not the result which I'm looking for :) `@muhammad-dyas-yaskur`

Comment: It's not clear to me what the goal is here. Are you trying to build a DataTable where each row can be expanded to show an embedded child DataTable (i.e. not just some static data, but an actual fully-functioning DataTable)? Or are you just trying to build a simple HTML child table for each row? What does your source data look like? Can you add some (formatted) examples?

Comment: Also, the typical way to use the [child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) feature is to fetch all your data (main table data and child row data) via a single DataTables ajax call. Is that what you want to do here (the same as the example from the DataTables web site)? Or are you trying to do something different?

Comment: `@andrewjames` please have a look at an image source I'm able to add image now, sorry my bad I follow [this blog](https://datatables.net/blog/2017-03-31)
 let me try to add some example, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after too many effort and exploring the web, successfully I found what I'm trying to achieve :)

here is the solution which I wrote if it helps others who may face the table structure related solution

In an ajax success call, I add class and whichever tag want to use

```
success: function ( json ) {
            div.html(json)
            div.removeClass( 'loading' )
            div.addClass('col-xl-12')
            if(json.length > 0){
                div.append("<table class='table-responsive'><thead><tr><th>TABLE FILEDS</th></tr></thead><tbody id='details'>")

                var tbody = $('#details')
                var len = json.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    tbody.append("<tr><td>"+[json]+"</td></tr>");
                }
                tbody.append('</tbody></table>')
            }
        }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
var newHtml = "";
   newHtml += '<tr>'+ addyourvariablecontent +'</tr>';
   var newConHtml = '<table><tbody>' + newHtml  + '</tbody></table>';
   $("#yourID").html(newConHtml);
// this will help you to solve the problem, you can call your data in creating html+ variable then you can append the your data.
```

Comment: can you help me out I couldn't reach a result which I'm trying to achieve I'm a newbie to the data-table concept

Comment: `@naveenkumar-p`

Comment: call the variable before the for loop the variable you can add the data what you get from your JSON.

Comment: `@naveenkumar-p` I edited my question please have a look if it clears your doubt about what actually I'm trying to explain :)